# Can I run Vmware Workstation installed machines with vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, vmware

I have kali linux virtual machines installed and run on vmware workstation

Now i want to run this machine using vagrant, is that possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes You can!**

You can do this by VMWare Integration Plugin, but that comes for a price.

Read more about it at [Pricing & Purchase](https://www.vagrantup.com/vmware/index.html).

Once you have the License, you can then do:

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-workstation
```

This will install the plugin.

You then need to supply License with:

```
vagrant plugin license vagrant-vmware-workstation ~/license.lic
```

Refer [Official docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vmware/installation.html) for more details.

Once everything is set up, you can then create a `vagrantfile`:

```
# vagrant init hashicorp/precise64

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
end
```

And then,

```
vagrant up --provider vmware_workstation
```

From Vagrant's [VMWare plugin usage](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vmware/usage.html) Docs:

> The Vagrant VMware providers are used just like any other provider.
>   Please read the general basic usage page for providers.
>
> The value to use for the --provider flag is vmware_fusion for VMware
>   Fusion, and vmware_workstation for VMware Workstation.
>
> The Vagrant VMware provider does not support parallel execution at
>   this time. Specifying the --parallel option will have no effect.

Once vmware is up, you can spin not just kali Linux, but any image you have.